# Android Studio displaying numbers and math actions

Tags: java, android, android-layout

tv and tv2 should display an math algoritm writen in "if" statement. 
Can someone help me solve this problem? this should do display the math action in tv if `((b/100)*a)c` and when button1 is clicked , else it should do `d/((bc)/100)` when button2 is clicked and displays it in tv2.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.marek.przelicznikpaliw;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        //pola
        EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
        EditText b1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pali);
        EditText c1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.litr);
        EditText d1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.koszt);

        // wynik
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKoszt);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKilometry);

        float a,b,c,d,wynik;
        a = Float.parseFloat(a1.getText().toString());
        b = Float.parseFloat(b1.getText().toString());
        c = Float.parseFloat(c1.getText().toString());
        d = Float.parseFloat(d1.getText().toString());
        wynik = 0;
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
            wynik = ((b / 100) * a)*c;
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            wynik = d/((b * c) / 100);
        }
        tv.setText(wynik+"");
        tv2.setText(wynik+"");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cel"
        android:hint="Ilosc km do celu to:"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pali"
        android:hint="Ile litrow pali na 100km"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cel" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/litr"
        android:hint="Cena za litr"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pali"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/litr"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Licz zlotowki"
        android:text="Licz koszty"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/koszt"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Za ile zl zostalo zatankowane gaz/paliwo?" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Licz kilometry"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/koszt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/emptystring"
        android:id="@+id/wynikKoszt"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/emptystring"
        android:id="@+id/wynikKilometry" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText a1;
    private EditText b1;
    private EditText c1; 
    private EditText d1; 
    private TextView tv;
    private TextView tv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //pola
        a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
        b1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pali);
        c1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.litr);
        d1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.koszt);

        // wynik
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKoszt);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKilometry);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float a = 0;
            float b = 0;
            float c = 0;
            float d = 0;
            float wynik = 0;

            try {
                a = Float.parseFloat(a1.getText().toString());
                b = Float.parseFloat(b1.getText().toString());
                c = Float.parseFloat(c1.getText().toString());
                d = Float.parseFloat(d1.getText().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                wynik = ((b / 100) * a) * c;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(wynik));
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {

                if((b * c == 0)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You can't divide by 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                wynik = d / ((b * c) / 100);
                tv2.setText(String.valueOf(wynik));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\Marek\AndroidStudioProjects\PrzelicznikPaliw\app\src\main\java\com\example\marek\przelicznikpaliw\MainActivity.java
Error:(55, 6) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.494 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                wynik = ((b / 100) * a) * c;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(wynik));
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                wynik = d / ((b * c) / 100);
                tv2.setText(String.valueOf(wynik));
            }
        }
    };
}


and if i set this like this the app wont run

Comment: I am missing an ; at the end of `onClickListener`. I just updated the answer, please try again. Let me know

Comment: Application Przelicznik Paliw has been freezed. Or how do you say that, it's written in polish sorry

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your last comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: "fuel conversion application has been stopped" when i try to run it on my phone it gets this error. Sorry just google translated

Comment: I made some other fixes. Please try now

Comment: but if i leave d1 empty the value wont display, it will popup incorrect value, can we change that?

Comment: I updated the code with your request. If you have other questions please open a new question on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013697/android-studio-android-scrolling-down-and-up-enable here

Answer (score 0):

according to the description you'have given, I think it should look like below:

```
  if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
        wynik = ((b / 100) * a)*c;
        tv.setText(wynik+"");
        tv2.setText("");
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        wynik = d/((b * c) / 100);
        tv2.setText(wynik+"");
        tv.setText("");
    }
```

is that you required?

Comment: Doesn't display the value of the actions in tv or tv2