# Android studio, android scrolling down and up enable

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to add something like scrolling from top to bottom and vice versa but i don't know how to add this function, i was trying with ScrollView but that gave nothing.

MainActivity.java :

```
    package com.example.marek.przelicznikpaliw;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText a1;
    private EditText b1;
    private EditText c1;
    private EditText d1;
    private TextView tv;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //pola
        a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
        b1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pali);
        c1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.litr);
        d1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.koszt);

        // wynik
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKoszt);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKilometry);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynikKosztx2);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                float a = 0;
                float b = 0;
                float c = 0;
                float d = 0;
                float wynik = 0;
                float wynik2 = 0;
                float wynik3 = 0;
            try {
                a = Float.parseFloat(a1.getText().toString());
                b = Float.parseFloat(b1.getText().toString());
                c = Float.parseFloat(c1.getText().toString());
                d = Float.parseFloat(d1.getText().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
                wynik = ((b / 100) * a) * c;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(wynik));
                wynik2 = (((b / 100) * a) * c)*2;
                tv3.setText(String.valueOf(wynik2));
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                wynik3 = d / ((b * c) / 100);
                tv2.setText(String.valueOf(wynik3));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
android:weightSum="1">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cel"
    android:hint="Ilosc km do celu to:"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pali"
    android:hint="Ile litrow pali na 100km"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cel"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/litr"
    android:hint="Cena za litr"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pali"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/litr"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Licz zlotowki"
    android:text="Licz koszty"
    android:clickable="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/koszt"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Za ile zl zostalo zatankowane gaz/paliwo?"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Licz kilometry"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/koszt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Dojedziesz w wybrany cel za(zł):"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/emptystring"
    android:id="@+id/wynikKoszt"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Oraz spowrotem za(zł):"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/emptystring"
    android:id="@+id/wynikKosztx2"
    android:layout_weight="0.06" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Za tę kwotę przejedziesz(km):"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/emptystring"
    android:id="@+id/wynikKilometry" />
```

Comment: You want to scroll the page when content isn't fitting the screen or irrespective of screen size

Comment: I don't know what do you mean

Comment: Do you want make your UI fully scrollable ?

Comment: I have maid it, added first ScrollView and then Layout, works good